# DaggerInjector not found in Android 3.0 with gradle:3.0.0-alpha9

Tags: android, gradle, dagger

In my `App.class`'s `onCreate()` I instantiate my `Injector` like this:

```
 injector = DaggerInjector
            .builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .build();
```

In the officiel Android Studio Release of 2.3 everything works as it should, but when using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 8 with the newest Gradle `2.5.0-alpha-preview-02` *(which is required to use the new font feature)* then `DaggerInjector` is never found, like it doesn't exist at all

**My stackstrace says only this:**

```
Error:(8, 47) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerInjector
Error:(45, 20) error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerInjector
```

Comment: Last Gradle version - 4.1-milestone-1, last android gradle plugin version - 3.0-alpha8. Check your versions

Comment: @DeKaNszn I just updated everything: now I use gradle `gradle:3.0.0-alpha9` and ` buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"` But still the same problem